Need to know a hindi movie name thiefs became lovers with girls in that house
I have watched a movie on Indian TV channel Doordarshan, in which 3 or 4 guys came to rob a house, there they fall in love with the girls in that house and ends with some funny climax. I need help in finding name of that movie. It's a Hindi movie.
This movie possibly released a decade ago. Climax is something like those loving pairs fighting for the wealth and money in that house. It was not serious fight. I don't recognize any actors in that movie.

Please add more content to the question.

So was it comedy film or just funny climax?
